# want to trigger an event when the user touch the left part of the display

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I have used the scrollviewer in my app to show images. i need to move the stackpanel inside the scrollviewer right side when the user touches the right side of the display,and to move on left when user touches the left side. I tries in XNA framework but vector2 class does not check the postion of finger. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hook into the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event of the page. And then calculate where the user touched the screen with the [MouseEventArgs.GetPosition Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190492%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Here's a basic example to demonstrate this concept:

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer Background="Red">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" 
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                Width="150" 
                Background="Black"  
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="48" Height="48" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>                
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseDown;
}

private void OnMouseDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
{
    Point pos = e.GetPosition( this );

    double half = this.ActualWidth / 2;

    if( pos.X < half )
    {
        MyStackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    }
    else
    {
        MyStackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }
}
```